# Why that if expression almost always evaluate to 1?

Tags: c

I tried to make a small program that prints all of the 3 digit numbers that each of their digits is different. This is what I wrote:

```
for(int i = 100; i<= 999; i++)
{
    if((i%10) != (i/10%10) != (i/100))
        printf("%d ",i);
}
```

Instead of printing : `101 102 103...`

it printed : `100 111 122 133...`

Why is this happening? For example, the number 100, that shouldn't be printed: If 0 != 0 != 1 print.

Answer (score 6):

Not:

```
a != b != c
```

But:

```
(a != b) && (a != c) && (b != c)
```

Have fun

Comment: can you explain _why_ it didn't work?

Comment: @nonamedelete `a != b != c` is not an expression that is true if a, b and c are all different, but it is equivalent to `(a != b) != c` which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: `a != b` will give approximately 90% 0, 10% 1. `(a != b) != c` will in approx, 10% be 1.

Comment: No, it's not about precedence. No programming language supports such a construct. IIRC, Python knows `a < b < c`, but your expression wants three comparisons, not two. -- BTW, Don't now comment "Thank you", please mark the answer as accepted.